# How to get the google map in emulator?

Tags: android, google-maps

I implemented a program to show google map in my application, it's working well in mobile but when i am trying run in emulator it's throwing below exception.
Can any one give suggestions.

```
 10-03 02:03:53.220: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(841): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3265100 but found 2012110
    10-03 02:03:53.240: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(841): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3265100 but found 2012110
    10-03 02:03:53.260: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(841): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3265100 but found 2012110
    10-03 02:03:53.270: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(841): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3265100 but found 2012110
    10-03 02:03:53.290: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(841): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3265100 but found 2012110
    10-03 02:03:53.330: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(841): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3265100 but found 2012110
    10-03 02:03:53.330: D/AndroidRuntime(841): Shutting down VM
    10-03 02:03:53.341: W/dalvikvm(841): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
    10-03 02:03:53.360: E/AndroidRuntime(841): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    10-03 02:03:53.360: E/AndroidRuntime(841): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't a question, it's a Logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Did you launch your emulator with target set to Google APIs?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is because maps v2 are not supported on emulator, You have to use real device.

Answer (score 0):

Google maps are not supported in the emulator even if you launch your emulator with target set to google api. You will need a real device to get the map.